# Folders in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Within Xcode there are Groups and Folders.  Groups are displayed as yellow icons and Folders are displayed as blue icons.  My question is :

Managed to add a folder within an Xcode project, but it seems that only one file can be put into the folder.  Have tried to drag a file to the folder but failed.  What is the best way to add files to a folder within Xcode ?

Hope that somebody familiar with this could help ...

Answer (score 0):

Folders are a bit odd as far as I have found out.

Normally I add folders as groups. And can move items around within them. But when moving the files in xcode they do not translate into those actual folders.

If i want to move an item within the groups and represent the move in the folder structure. I would move the item in finder, then re add the item from that group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am thinking of using folder because I wish to add a UIWebView which refers to local html files.  But the strategy may not be a good one.  May be I should use group instead ...

Comment: well when the items are placed in your bundle. they are flattened anyhow. so any duplicate files will be overwritten with the last one encountered. A better bet is something I do. I name my items in the bundle with _ instead of / for the folders. then i move them from the bundle to the Documents folder and create a directory for them by replacing the _ with /

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I thought that by using folders within Xcode I could use same named files in different folders.  Agree with what you've suggested, we can always use some kind of naming scheme to simulate the effect of traditional folders ...